# Writing strings to a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I am generating some random strings in python using the following code:

```
import string
import random
import os
passphrases = []
pass_file = open("Passphrases2.txt","w")
os.chmod("Passphrases2.txt",0o777)
for _ in range(100):
    st = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(random.randint(8,16)))
    passphrases.append(st)
    print(st)
for p in passphrases:
    pass_file.write("\n"%p)
```

I want these strings to be stored in a text file in the same directory as the python code.

When I execute this code, a file named `Passphrases2.txt` gets created but it is empty in the first execution.

When I execute the same code for the second time, the file gets updated with the strings that were generated during the first execution, then on running the third time, it gets updated with the strings generated in the second execution and so on. I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `.close()` file or use `with` statement.

This is including some optimizations:

```py
import os
from random import choice, randint
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
with open("Passphrases2.txt", "w") as pass_file:
    for _ in range(1000):
        st = "".join(choice(alphabet) for i in range(randint(8, 16)))
        print(st)
        pass_file.write(f"{st}\n")

os.chmod("Passphrases2.txt", 0o777)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import string
import random
import os

passphrases = []
for _ in range(100):
    st = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(random.randint(8,16)))
    passphrases.append(st)
    print(st)

with open("Passphrases2.txt","w") as pass_file:
    for p in passphrases:
        pass_file.write("%s\n" %p)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are missing `pass_file.close()` at the end to properly close the file handle after finishing to write. Without properly closing, the write to file was not fully flushed and saved. It's like you are typing something in Notepad but have not yet hit the save button.

Then on the 2nd run, `pass_file = open("Passphrases2.txt","w")`, reopening the file handle will close the previous handle; this will act like `pass_file.close()` for the previous run and thus you are seeing previous data on 2nd run and so on.

You may add `pass_file.close()` after the last for loop or use the Python `with` statement to ensure file handle open is being closed properly after it is done.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the file in the end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).